# I got an error while using FormData jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I have used FormData jquery for upload images, but images are not in the uploads folder. I think I am not following FormData in correct way. My Firebug console and JS are given below. Please check the code and correct me.

Firebug Console Post

Source
-----------------------------55572121128376
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"

title=2&subtitle=2&circle=2&text=&price=2&pseudo_price=2&link=2&color=#8b8b8b&column=2&addForm=addForm
&ID=70
-----------------------------55572121128376-- 
Form

```
<input name="image" type="file" id="file" >
```

JS

```
function saveData(id){
     var ID             = id;
     var title          = $("#title_"+ID).val();
     var subtitle       = $("#subtitle_"+ID).val();
     var circle         = $("#circle_"+ID).val();
     var text           = $("#text_"+ID).val();
     var price          = $("#price_"+ID).val();
     var pseudo_price   = $("#pseudoprice_"+ID).val();
     var link           = $("#link_"+ID).val();
     var color          = $("#color_"+ID).val();
     var column         = $("#column_"+ID).val();
     var addForm        = 'addForm';
     var dataString     = 'title='+title+'&subtitle='+subtitle+'&circle='+circle+'&text='+text+'&price='+price+'&pseudo_price='+pseudo_price+'&link='+link+'&color='+color+'&column='+column+'&addForm='+addForm+'&ID='+ID;
     var formdata       = new FormData();
     formdata.append('image', dataString);
     $.ajax({
     type: "post",
     url: "insert.php",
     data: formdata,
     cache: false,
     processData: false,
     contentType: false,
     success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
     }
     });
};
```

insert.php

```
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {

    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]);
    $uploadOk = 1;
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Check file size
    if ($_FILES["image"]["size"] > 500000) {
        echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }

// Allow certain file formats
    if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
        && $imageFileType != "gif"
    ) {
        echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
    if ($uploadOk == 0) {
        echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
    } else {
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
            echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["image"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";
        } else {
            echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use form data like this

```
var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standart javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('image', dataString);
// now rest of your code 
...
```

Comment: Thank you so much I got it.

Comment: your subtitle is not a array and if you try to use it as a array then it will give you a error... same goes for something that is a array and tried to use as a string

Comment: Without below section. I can easily update the data using data:dataString, but data: formdata, it will occurs error.                                                                                                    var form = $('form')[0]; // You need to use standart javascript object here
var formData = new FormData(form);
formData.append('image', dataString);

Comment: if its up to you then i will recommend you a third party plugin to upload files,  https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload
 which has multiple options for file upload, with addition to upload progress size, errors and previews, once file uploaded submit the rest of the form with ajax

Comment: Thanks. var_dump($_POST) result is given below. How can i store this in a variable                                         array(10) {
  ["title"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["subtitle"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["circle"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["text"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  ["price"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
  ["pseudoprice"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
   ["column"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(1) "3"
  }
  ["hiddenid"]=>
  string(2) "70"
}

Comment: `$_POST['title'][0]` and  `$_POST['subtitle'][0]`

Comment: Thanks for this stuff.